# Constructing a linq query to get associations

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have 2 tables, Category and ProductCategory.

A product can have multiple categories:

### **Category**

<kbd>CategoryId</kbd><kbd>CategoryName</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>              
<kbd>Electronics</kbd>     
<kbd>2</kbd>              
<kbd>E-Reader</kbd>     
<kbd>3</kbd>              
<kbd>Tablet</kbd>

### **ProductCategory**

<kbd>CategoryId</kbd><kbd>ProductId</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>              
<kbd>100</kbd>     
<kbd>2</kbd>              
<kbd>100</kbd>     
<kbd>3</kbd>              
<kbd>100</kbd>     
<kbd>3</kbd>              
<kbd>500</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>              
<kbd>800</kbd>

I have a repository set up for Category that has a navigation property to ProductCategory.
I am trying to construct a LINQ query that takes a CategoryId and return me a list of all the 
associated Categories + Number of times it is associated (Association being through product).

For example if we take CategoryId 1 (Electronics) from the above example:
We can see that 1 is linked to ProductId 100 and 800 but at the same time ProductId 100 is linked to Categories 2 & 3. We also see that CategoryId 2 is linked one times to ProductId 100 and CategoryId 3 is linked 2 times to ProductIds 100 and 500.

My expected result set would be (excluding the CategoryId of 1 that was passed in)

<kbd>CategoryId</kbd><kbd>Association(s)</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>              
<kbd>1</kbd>     
<kbd>3</kbd>              
<kbd>2</kbd>

But My problem is if I do something like this:

var resultSet = repository.Query()
                .Include(pc => pc.ProductCategory)
                .Where(c => c.CategoryId == 1).ToList();

the resultSet is only restricted to

<kbd>CategoryId</kbd><kbd>ProductId</kbd>
<kbd>1</kbd>              
<kbd>100</kbd>     
<kbd>1</kbd>              
<kbd>800</kbd>

but using above LINQ I want to shape the resultSet to:

<kbd>CategoryId</kbd><kbd>Association(s)</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>              
<kbd>1</kbd>     
<kbd>3</kbd>              
<kbd>2</kbd>

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the count of associations which is an aggregate function that you can use directly against a grouped selection from product category.

```
var results = ProductCategory
    .GroupBy(g => g.CategoryId)
    .Select(new { 
        Category = g.Key, 
        Associations = g.Count() 
        })
    .ToList();
```